# Azure File Storage URL in browser showing InvalidHeaderValue

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I am trying to access the URL given in Azure for a file on the Azure File Storage format, however I am getting this error below.  Is it possible to get this?  Why would they offer a public URL when it's useless?  Also how can I access this directly from IIS?

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
<Message>
The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format. RequestId:5d681103-0a1a-00cc-5555-5s4849000000 Time:2016-02-04T14:06:50.1786949Z
</Message>
<HeaderName>x-ms-version</HeaderName>
<HeaderValue/>
</Error>
```

Comment: Please see if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045880/cannot-access-windows-azure-file-storage-document/35046177#35046177

Comment: Why event have a public URL then?

Comment: It is a URL and not a public URL. Furthermore, you can create a Shared Access Signature (say with read permission), append it to the URL and then you should be able to access the file directly.

Comment: Then how can we make a public url e.g. www.websitename.com which could open that index file from our hosting?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I had the same error message when using `New-AzRmStorageShare`, when I'd included the `-AccessTier` parameter.  Dropping that parameter, all worked as expected.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Gaurav already mentioned a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045880/cannot-access-windows-azure-file-storage-document/35046177#35046177) where it says you should use a "Shared Access Signature". In your storage account settings in Azure you'll find a topic "Shared Acess Signature". After clicking "Generate SAS" you'll get a "SAS Token" which you need to append to your URL.

[image: Shared Access Signature]

Comment: Instead of generating SAS token, it's recommended to generate a SAS derived from Stored Access Policy. May refer to the [steps given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69566546/4311268).

Answer (score 11):

If you use Azure File service to share your files, you have to add SAS token after your resources URL. e.g. https://testiiju5zra.file.core.windows.net/alexaskillaudio/lamb.mp3?sv=SDFCSGDJ01231%&SDDFXsuSDFSDSDSSFD

Alternatively, you can do the exact same things by using Azure Blobs as well. If you use Blobs, you don't have to add the extra token after resources URL. Just create a container on Blobs and make it public. And you can access your file like
https://testiiju5zra.blob.core.windows.net/blobaudiosource/lamb.mp3

Comment: What if I want to make an azure file share public without the token. A lot of my calls will be http gets from web pages where I am not able to append this token

Answer (score 7):

Mike,
The error you received indicates that you are missing x-ms-version header. But once you set it, you will receive another error if you have not authenticated. 
You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194274.aspx for list of required headers.
Alternatively, you can use [client library](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/) for the requests instead of REST API.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a blob instead. Here is an article how to set it up.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal

Answer (score 1):

This error is also caused by missing/incorrect connection string in `local.settings.json` file

Your file should like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```