# Error using loopback-storage-component to upload/download files to azure storage

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using the LoopBack storage component to upload and download files to azure cloud storage as illustrated on their [documentation](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Storage-component.html)
I've created model named container in model-config.json

```
 "container": {
    "dataSource": "storage",
    "public": true
  }
```

with datasource in datasouce.json

```
"storage": {
    "name": "storage",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": 'azure',
    "storageAccount": "xxxxx",
    "storageAccessKey": "xxxx"
  }
```

Now I've a REST API, as described in their documentation. here's the error I've got each time I call one of the generated GET /api/containers endpoint.

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 400,
    "message": "azure Error (400): Bad Request",
    "provider": "azure",
    "failCode": "Bad Request",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "href": "http://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/xml",
      "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
      "x-ms-request-id": "820995fc-0001-013e-7b9a-48de28000000",
      "date": "Sun, 27 Nov 2016 10:40:02 GMT",
      "cache-control": "proxy-revalidate",
      "content-length": "328",
      "connection": "close"
    },
    "result": {
      "err": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.\nRequestId:820995fc-0001-013e-7b9a-48de28000000\nTime:2016-11-27T10:40:02.3522933Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-version</HeaderName><HeaderValue>2011-08-18</HeaderValue></Error>"
    }
  }
}
```

after searching for this error I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203205/azure-file-storage-url-in-browser-showing-invalidheadervalue) answer my question is whether I have to set the header manually and how to do it or there's a missing configuration for azure storage for loopback-storage-component.

I added this piece of code to common/models/container.js and I get the same error.

```
module.exports = function(Container) {
  Container.beforeRemote('**', function(context, user, next) {
    //2015-12-11
    context.res.set('x-ms-version', '2015-12-11');
    next();
  });
};
```

Comment: Try setting the header manually first and update your question

Comment: To [list the containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/List-Containers2?redirectedfrom=MSDN) under the specified account via REST API,  **Authorization**, **Date** (or **x-ms-date**) and **x-ms-version** should be required in request header. Please use Fiddler to check the request headers and the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the [example-2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services) with the same configuration in `model-config.json` & `datasouce.json` with you, it works fine on my side without any other configuraitons or addtionally code modifications.

Could  you provide more details about the environment and the sdk version you are using. You can try to update your dependencies, the dependencies in my test is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "errorhandler": "^1.1.1",
    "loopback": "^2.0.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.0.0",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^2.1.0",
    "loopback-component-storage": "^1.5.0",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

At last, you can try to modify the souce code of `pkgcloud` change `2011-08-18` to `2015-12-11` at https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud/blob/master/lib/pkgcloud/azure/utils/constants.js#L2048

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I've tried the example-2.0 project with my configs and changed the dependencies in package.json. here's my dependencies `"dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "errorhandler": "^1.1.1",
    "loopback": "^2.22.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^2.4.0",
    "loopback-component-storage": "^1.10.0",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.39.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
  }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the storage deployment type. I created storage with Azure  classic deployment models however, when I changed the deployment model to "Azure Resource Manager" it worked well. The difference can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model).