# ERROR: The specifed resource name contains invalid characters. ErrorCode: InvalidResourceName

Tags: azure-devops, blob, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage, azure-storage-account

ERROR: The specifed resource name contains invalid characters. ErrorCode: InvalidResourceName

2019-10-31T10:28:17.4678189Z `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidResourceName</Code><Message>The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.`

2019-10-31T10:28:17.4678695Z RequestId:

`2019-10-31T10:28:17.4679207Z Time:2019-10-31T10:28:17.4598301Z</Message></Error>`

I am trying to deploy my static website to blob storage in azure with azure DevOps, but I am getting this error. In my pipeline, I am using grunt build to build, and archive it to zip, then publishing to the azure pipeline, then in the release, I am extracting files, and trying to upload these files with azure CLI task.

I am using following command 
`az storage blob upload-batch --account-name something --account-key something --destination ‘$web’ --source ./`

My Container name is $web

Comment: provide more informartion and describe your error

Comment: probably your blob\container name contain capital letters or dashes or something similar, you are only allowed to use [a-z0-9] in your storage\container\blob names

Comment: I have enabled static web site in an azure storage account, afterward, $web container automatically created in containers. I am only providing '$web' destination in CLI command, I have checked it, I didn't use _ or capitals characters

Comment: I am getting the same error to read Azure File Storage or File Containers from Logic APP. Please let me know if anyone has a solution to that.

Answer (score 33):

Permitted characters are lowercase a-z 0-9 and *single*, *infix*, hyphens

```
[a-z0-9\-]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata

Comment: Worth pointing out explicitly it is _lower_ case

Comment: This was so easy, after 3 hours I can't use underscores in filename.

Answer (score 14):

I solved this problem by removing apostrophes around container name:
`az storage blob upload-batch --account-name something --account-key something --destination $web --source ./`

Comment: Thank you! I had the exact same problem, spent 4 hours on this, would probably spend 4 more if it wasn't for this answer :)

Answer (score 3):

verify container name or coonection string might contain extra/nonallowed symbols... In my case it was having extra spaces in container name

Comment: This solved my issue. I had a "_" instead of "-" in the storage *container* name! Thank you @madhusudhan-v-indian

Comment: Thanks for this, in my case I was trying to PUT a blob in a container referenced in all caps while the container name was all in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not solve your problem, but it will solve a related problem for other people:

If the aim is to simply download a file from Azure File Storage using a link, after generating a SAS token, as shown here: [Azure File Storage URL in browser showing InvalidHeaderValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203205/azure-file-storage-url-in-browser-showing-invalidheadervalue)

If you remove the slash after the name of the file in the generated link, the file will download!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was caused by an incorrect container name