# Azure File Storage URL in browser showing InvalidQueryParameterValue error even after appending SAS token

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I uploaded some files to an Azure File Storage.
Generated the SAS key and appended it to the link as instructed here: [Azure File Storage URL in browser showing InvalidHeaderValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203205/azure-file-storage-url-in-browser-showing-invalidheadervalue)

But I am still getting the InvalidQueryParameterValue error when I try to access the files using the link.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the URL of the file you’re trying to access and the error message you’re getting. Please  obfuscate account name and the sig part of query string before sharing the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with using the **[Azure storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/)** in my system

combine the **URL** from file properties , **remove the `/` from the end the URL Form file**  with **SAS token**.

Example URL:

**https://testsasex.file.core.windows.net/testsas/test.txt?sv=2020-04-08&ss=f&srt=sco**

**1)** Click on the file ,select the **properties** next  copy the **URL from file properties**

[image]

**2)** Generate SAS From [Azure storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/) .

Right click on the storage in Storage explorer and select the **Generate shared access signature**.

[image]

**3)** Select **File** and add permissions and click on **Create**.

[image]

**3)**  A second **Shared Access Signature dialog** will then display that lists the blob container along with the **URL(Connection String) and QueryStrings** you can use to access the storage resource. Select Copy next to the URL you wish to copy to the clipboard

[image]

**4)**  After that ,combine the URL  **(Remove / from URL)** from file properties and SAS token

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly!

I have no idea why, but the problem arises from that slash you said to remove (the one directly after test.txt in your example).

I can simply copy the link I was generating earlier, remove that slash and it works!

So weird lol.