# Handling SAS tokens using shared access policy (azure storage)

Tags: azure-storage, iot

I am sending blobs to an Azure Storage account. I have one customer with 3 IOT clients who each write to their own container.

I use a share access policy to create a SAS URI to each container.

I am not using an expire data when creating the shared access policy. The generated SAS URI is copied to a config file that each of the clients use this to write blobs to the storage.

This works fine. On the client I create the container using

```
CloudBlobContainer _container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri("https://myhubstorage.blob.core.windows.net/containername?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&si=containername&sig=xxxxx"));
```

The token above is retrieved from a config file

To send blobs I use

```
var newBlob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);
```

Now this works, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach. The reason is that I do not have an expiry on the shared access policy used to create the container SAS token. I don't want to distribute a new SAS token for the container each time it expires (would have to update the config file.
Also I do not want the clients to have access to the storage account key).

If a client is compromised I can revoke the shared access policy so the other clients will not be affected.

But is this the best approach to solve this regarding security? Input would be appreciated.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206993

Answer (score 1):

Using a shared access policy is suggested, however, you may need to notice that you can set up to 5 stored access policies for a container (It looks not a problem for you since there are only 3 IoT clients).

You might also want to refer to [best practices for using SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#best-practices-when-using-sas) for a full list.