# How many access policies can I create and add on the same one Azure container?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, limit, quota

I didn't find the answer by search. I thought I should be able to create many stored access policies on one container (at least thousands). But by tests, my program can only add up to 5 policies on one container.

Then I tried Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, it also has this restriction, can add only up to 5. But I cannot find any description about this. Is there any way to remove this restriction? Thanks.

Comment: We also could get more Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits).

Comment: @TomSun Thanks for that

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206993/how-to-revoke-shared-access-signature-in-azure-sdk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The access policy limit is indeed 5 stored access policies per container, file share, table, or queue. And there's no way to alter this. The limit is documented within Azure's Storage scalability and Performance Targets document, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/scalability-targets#scale-targets-for-blob-storage).

Note: You are able to generate Shared Access Signatures independently of the stored access policies. These are just more limited (e.g. you cannot revoke a SAS; it's active until the time expires, unless you delete the blob).